# Firebird Embedded & Delphi "unavailable database"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird, firebird-embedded

I'm using Firebird 2.5 (Embedded) And Delphi XE2.
I kept below files to my aplication root dir :

- C:\myapp\app.exe
- C:\myapp\fbclient.dll
- C:\myapp\icudt30.dll
- C:\myapp\icuin30.dll
- C:\myapp\icuuc30.dll
- C:\myapp\dbxfb.dll

And My Connection Settings :

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Con: TSQLConnection;
 begin
  Con := TSQLConnection.Create(Self); 
    With Con Do
     Begin
       Connected := False;
       DriverName := 'FirebirdConnection';

       Params.Clear;
       Params.Add('DriverName=' + DriverName);
       Params.Add('User_Name=SYSDBA');
       Params.Add('Password=masterkey');
       Params.Add('Database=C:\GHARARDAD.FDB');
       Params.Add('SQLDialect=3');

       LoginPrompt := False;
       ConnectionName := 'Gharardad';
       LibraryName := 'dbxfb.dll';
       VendorLib := 'C:\fbclient.dll'; // Renamed fbembed.dll to fbclient.dll
       GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverInterBase'; 
       Connected := True;
     End;
    End;
```

My Operation sys is : `Win 7 64 bit` 
And FB embedde ver is : `Firebird-2.5.1.26351-0_Win32_embed`
And my app Compiled on 32 bit

DLL Sizes :

```
 fbembed.dll  ----->  size    3,784,704 bytes

 dbxfb.dll     -----> size    288,768 bytes
```

But when i want to Run application, I get following Error:

> DBX Error: Driver could not be properly. Client may be misiing, not
>   installed properly, of the wrong version, or thr driver may be misiing
>   from the system path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your connection string to database?

Comment: @Marcodor - Edited First Post.

Comment: But My Error has been changed to "DBX Error: Database Must be specified."

Comment: Maybe DriverName := 'Firebird' instead of 'FirebirdConnection'?

Comment: @Erwin. No. Does't work.

Comment: The error has changed?! You mean, you changed something that led to that effect, or at random, you get different errors?

Comment: Too bad you changed your question and makes @Marcodor answer invalid.  Why do you establish the connectionName after setting parameters?  Do you know what the ConnectionName property means?

Comment: 1) fbclient.dll is not of Firebird Embedded. Where did  you take it from ?

Comment: 2) what shows Process Monitor  ? which FB DLL is got loaded by program ?

Comment: 3) Is your program Win32 or Win64 ? you can not load Win64 dll from Win32 program or vice versa. If u make Win32 app it would not load Win64 FB DLL. Check dll load events in Process Monitor.

Comment: 4) even if your DLL is really FB Emb, then it is still not fully deployed. I named firebird.msg and fbintl.dll files. Check in the Process Monitor that they are found and loaded okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you use ConnectionName if you allready specify database User_Name Password.

I would prefer something like this :

```
 Con := TSQLConnection.Create(Self); 
    With Con Do
     Begin
       Connected := False;
       DriverName := 'FirebirdConnection';      
       LibraryName := 'dbxfb.dll';
       VendorLib := 'fbembed.dll';
       ConnectionName := 'Gharardad';
       Params.Value['User_Name'] := 'SYSDBA';
       Params.Value['Password'] := 'masterkey';
       Params.Value['Database'] := 'C:\GHARARDAD.FDB';
       Connected := True;
     End;
```

Comment: First Post Edited. And i get new Error

Comment: You have to use Firebird embedded 32 bit if you compile in 32 bit

Answer (score 4):

1. You need specify Database parameter like this:

   Params.Add('Database=C:\Full\Path\GHARARDAD.FDB');
2. I see you want to use embedded version, you need to use *fbembed.dll* insead of *fbclient.dll*

Comment: !Marcodor- Before i set upon code. I get error "DBX Error: Database Must be specified" . And after use upon code i get "unavilable Databse"

Comment: @Marcodor- My db path is C:\GHARARDAD.FDB. Help me please

Comment: what is your operating system ? r u sure it will gave someone read-write access to the root of system disk ? is file virtualization engaged for application, so it would truly try to open the file from different hidden folder instead to protect system safety ? track FB-related file accesses with Process Monitor. Try to move DB file into your user folder where you surely have all grants on it.

Comment: @harmedkamrava - he also told you to use embedded version. fbclient.dll is not embedded

Answer (score 1):

Do u have any other connections open to that database ?

FlameRobin, IBExpert, Delphi IDE Form Designer ?

Do you have any active datasets/connections in Delphi ?

Embedded requires non-shareable opening of file.

Run SysInternals Process Explorer and do search for your database file if it is already open by some another application

---

Do u really use weirdly renamed firebird embedded and not firebird client ?
@Marcodor and @Re0sless already asked you that.

It seems that you only think you're using embedded but u only have small share of server installed without main engine.

```
fbembed.dll   2.5.1   Win32   size is 3 784 704 bytes
fbclient.dll  2.5.1   Win64   size is 870 912 bytes
fbclient.dll  2.5.1   Win32   size is 548 864 bytes
```

Which is yours DLL ?

---

This can also be that database engine version and database file version do not match. Try SysInternals Process Monitor to see which files does your application try to find and open. Does it succesfully open the db files ? does it successfully find and open firebird.msg ? does it succesfully open  icu*.dll ? maybe udf dlls ?

Is there some error written into firebird.log ?

In general - learn to use SysInternals Process Monitor to know what files and where were tried. It very frequently would hint you what error happened exactly and why.

---

You did not listed fbintl.dll
If your database containst non-Latin letters and non-English language, then it might be unable to open it without properly located fbintl. Check in Process Monitor where it is searched for and put there.

---

check in Process Monitor which firebird dll version your application actually loads. Is its version new enough to open that database ?

Answer (score 1):

You said your using Firebird embedded but you are using the standard firebird VendorLib

```
VendorLib := 'fbclient.dll';
```

For embedded firebird this should be

```
VendorLib = '[pathtolib]\fbembed.dll'
```

You are also missing the value for GetDriverFunc

So the complete TSQLConnection object would looks like so (tested in Delphi 2007)

```
Con := TSQLConnection.Create(Self); 
With Con Do
 Begin
   Connected := False;
   DriverName := 'FirebirdConnection';

   Params.Clear;
   Params.Add('DriverName=' + DriverName);
   Params.Add('User_Name=SYSDBA');
   Params.Add('Password=masterkey');
   Params.Add('Database=C:\GHARARDAD.FDB');
   Params.Add('SQLDialect=3');
   //other connection params here

   ConnectionName := 'Gharardad';
   LibraryName := 'dbxfb.dll';
   VendorLib := 'C:\fbembed.dll';
   GetDriverFunc = 'getSQLDriverInterBase' //Or what ever the dbxfb.dll function is called
   Connected := True;
 End;
End;
```

Note that the getSQLDriverInterBase function is the name of the function from the Devart firebird library so it may differ in the dbxfb.dll library.

Comment: he should not name a function, but a driver name constant.  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection

Though for light-weight application with FB Emb, i'd definitely prefered native lean components like Unified Interbase